# unique and unlist function alternative R

Tags: r

I have a huge (More than 10 Million rows), and I need to get the count as mentioned below.

For this, I will check first all the unique ones like this.

```
 lev<-(unique(unlist(mtcars[,8:11])))
```

Then count using the table function.

```
 as.data.frame(sapply(mtcars[,8:11], function(x) table(factor(x, levels = lev))))
```

But the above will work only for small datasets. Most of the time, R will kill this command if I use it for a large dataset.

Is there any suggestion/way to improve speed for large datasets, for example, for using dplyr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps a `data.table` approach might work for you

it first melts the data to a long format, and then casts to wide again. This automatically gets the unique values (=rows), and the length of these values (the default fun.aggregate for dcast.data.table) by column (i.e. variable).

```
DT <- as.data.table(mtcars)  # or setDT(mydata)
dcast(melt(DT[,8:11], measure.vars = names(DT)[8:11]),
      value ~ variable)
#    value vs am gear carb
# 1:     0 18 19    0    0
# 2:     1 14 13    0    7
# 3:     2  0  0    0   10
# 4:     3  0  0   15    3
# 5:     4  0  0   12   10
# 6:     5  0  0    5    0
# 7:     6  0  0    0    1
# 8:     8  0  0    0    1
```